# Best way to filter a geojson in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, geojson, react-leaflet

I am looking to filter a [geojson](https://github.com/timwis/leaflet-choropleth/blob/gh-pages/examples/basic/crimes_by_district.geojson) like this one, by feeding it an array of ids that correspond to the specific property I want to filter on. I am using React and leaflet and essentially want to filter out my map.

So let's say in my geojson linked above there are a series of multipolygons. I want to filter with the following index `let ids = [0,1,5,6]` so that only the multi polygons with that id (object_id in this case) will show. Not sure how to approach this. I was attempting to use the geojson filter capability provided by leaflet, but unsure how to implement. Below is what i have so far based off this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189988/filtering-geojson-data-to-include-in-leaflet-map):

```js
import L from 'react-leaflet';

geoFilter = (feature, id) => {
  if (feature.properties.index_right === id) return true;
};

//FILTER GEOJSON
sliceGeo = async () => {
  let ids = [0, 1, 5, 6];
  ids.map(id => {
    //FOR EACH INDEX ITEM FILTER
    let data = L.geoJson(myJson, { filter: sliceGeo((id = id)) }).addTo(map);
    return data;
  });
};
```

I think I am probably doing this in a very inefficient and incorrect way so hoping someone can push me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

It's good to make function which return filter function. Like this:

```
const filterByIds = (ids) => {
  return futures => ids.every(id => feature.properties.index_right === id)
}
```

This function takes an array of IDs, and returns filter function specialized for the IDs. For example, Giving `[1, 2, 3]`, returning `features => [1, 2, 3].every(id => feature.properties.index_right === id`. This filter function checks if `includes index_right` in `[1, 2, 3]`.

Add:

I examined and found more useful function.

```
const filterByIds = (ids) => {
  return futures => ids.includes(feature.properties.index_right)
}
```

Usage:

```
const ids = [0, 1, 5, 6];
const data = L.geoJson(myJson, { filter: filterByIds(ids) }).addTo(map);
```

Filter takes function so tend to think that should give it as removing parentheses, but in case function returns function, call function normally with parentheses. The above is so.

Comment: Thanks for this! But I am unsure how to apply this properly. Could you give me an example of how to use the `filterByIds` function? It seems I shouldn't be mapping the ids anymore?

Comment: Add usage. Just simple!

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
let ids = [0, 1, 5, 6];

geoFilter = (feature) => {
    return ids.includes(feature.properties.index_right)
};

L.geoJson(myJson, { filter: geoFilter }).addTo(map);
```

geoJson filter options need a function with one parameter (the feature), i change your callback with Array.prototype includes() function that return true if ids array contain feature.properties.index_right in it.

Comment: where is the `map` declaration coming from? i'm familiar with that concept only in the `leaflet` package, and not `react-leaflet`. there is the `useMap` hook but that's not doing the same thing when i try that.